# C++, determine prime number

Tags: c++

I've started to read a book on C++ yesterday. So far I'm 100 pages and took that number to write my first programm. I've wanted it to find out if a given number is a prime number or not.

I've got 2 questions about it.

1. I know my method is everything else than good. The programm is checking every single number which makes the programm big. What would be the ideal way to do this? Doesn't matter if I understand your answer yet, I'll simply read up the commands later :).
2. I've had a huge problem with the `"Result+=1"` line. At first I had `i=1`, which gave me the following result for the number `7`.

   1111112

Well, I also know why. For the 6 first for loops he found one number `(1)` and for the last one `2(1,7)`. But thats obviously not how I wanted it work. I want Result to be some kind of counter. How do I do that?

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



// Hauptprogramm

int main ()
{
    // Variablen
    int Prime_number;
    int Result = 0;

    // Abfragen
    cout << "Please enter possible prime number: ";
    cin >> Prime_number;

    // Rechnen
    for (int i=2; i <= Prime_number ; i++)
    {   
            if (Prime_number%i == 0)
            {   
                    Result +=1;
            }
    }

    // Ausgabe
    if(Result == 1)
    {
            cout << "You got a prime number!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
            cout << "No luck" <<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't see how this code would go so badly wrong. Suggest debugger or println of Prime_number to see how far it will loop.

Comment: You can read on available algorithms here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test.

Comment: Hello, nono - it's working. I would simply like to know how to do it better.

Comment: If you are interested more in this you should probably read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test but be aware some of these tests require a basic understanding of the math behind it (modular arithmetic)

Comment: You might also be interested in [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) (which is also cited in te previous given reference).

Comment: @jweyrich In that case I would rather recommend Sieve of Atkin.

Comment: Realyn: do not declare variables in the beginning. Declare close to usage. Das ist mehr richtig.

Comment: @Layne nice. Didn't know about the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is curious, and as you say very inefficient. Here's a better logic

Check every number from 2 to Prime_number - 1, if any *one* of them divides exactly then it is *not* a prime number, otherwise it is. The important point is that you stop looking after you find one divisor, because then you know the answer to your question. Here's some code that does that

```
bool prime = true;
for (i = 2; i < Prime_Number; ++i)
{
    if (Prime_Number % i == 0)
    {
        prime = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (prime)
    cout << "You got a prime number!" << endl;
else
    cout << "No luck" <<endl;
```

I think the two points you missed in your attempt were the use of a `bool` variable, and the fact that you can `break` out of a loop once you know its finished.

This code can be improved further by the way, but that's an exercise for you.

Answer (score 1):

A much more efficient approach can be seen in the following code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
bool isprime(int a)
{
    int count=0;
    for(int i=2;i<sqrt(a);i++)
    {
        if(a%i==0)
        {count++;}
    }
    if(a==1||count!=0) return false;
    else return true;
}
int main()
{
  int a;
  cin>>a;
  if(isprime(a))
  {
    cout<<"number is prime";
  }
  else cout<<"number is not prime";
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this reduces the number test cases in the isprime function exponentially, making the code much more efficient.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your method is pretty solid, regarding your questions:

Why do I start on i=2?

Well my definition of a prime number is a number that has 2 factors: 1 and itself. So when you start on one you (correct) count an extra factor as prime_number is exactly divisible by 1. This then gives you a result count of 2 because it found two factors.

What is the better way?

There are several better ways, some significantly more complex; however the algorithm you have now can be easily improved in several direct ways:

- As soon as you find any factor which is not either 1 or primenumber
  then you know the number is not prime, as soon as any
  (primenumber%i)==0 you could set a flag like *IsPrime=false* and
  *break* out of the loop.
- Even for a prime number you don't really need to go up to primenumber as the biggest factor possible is primenumber/2 - so your loop would be twice as fast and work just as well in this case. 2. EDIT: Actually if you think about it a bit the square root of primenumber is a good enough limit because all factors come in pairs and the smaller factor is always within this limit.

Hope you have fun learning.

Comment: In fact you need not go upto number/2. Checking upto sqrt(number) should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following code as well:

```
#include "time.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    div_t divresult;
    time_t t1,t2;   
    t1 = time(NULL); 
    int prime[1501] = {0};
    prime[1] = 2;
    prime[2] = 3;
    prime[3] = 5;
    prime[4] = 7;
    prime[5] = 11;
    int count = 6;

    for(int i = 12; count < 1500; i +=1)
    {
        bool Bprime = true; 
        for(int j = 1; j < count; j+=1)
        {
            if(i%prime[j] == 0) Bprime = false;
        }
        if(Bprime == true) prime[count++] = i;
    }
    t2 = time(NULL);
    divresult = div(t2-t1,60);
    cout<<divresult.quot <<" min "<<divresult.rem<<" sec"<<endl;
    int n = 0;
    cout<<"Give Value of N:";
    cin>> n;
    cout<<n<<"th prime is: "<<prime[n-1]<<endl;     

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <cmath>

bool BePrime(unsigned int N){
    if(N == 2) return true;

    for(int i = 2; i <= int(sqrt(N)); i++) {
        if(N%i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

main(){
    int a;
    while(scanf("%d",&a)){
        if(BePrime(a)) {
            printf("%d is Prime\n", a);
            continue;
        }
        printf("%d is not Prime\n", a);
    }

}
```