# Prime Numbers Exercise - Loop Issue C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to solve an exercise written in the Stroustrup's book about calculating and printing if a number between 1 and 100 is a prime number or not.

My code seems to work perfectly but, when it prints values on the screen, it starts from 6 and not from 2.

I have tried to figure out why but I am not able to understand the reason of that.

Can you lend me an hand?

Thank you very much!

```
 // Prime Numbers.cpp : definisce il punto di ingresso dell'applicazione console.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

vector<int> primes = { 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97 };

int primecheck(int x) {

    for (int i : primes) {
        if (x <= primes[i])
            break;
        if (primes[i] == x)
            return 1;
        while (x % primes[i] != 0) {
            --i;
            if (i < 0) {
                return 1;
                break;
            }
            else {
                if (x % primes[i] == 0)
                return 2;
            }
        }
    }
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
        if (primecheck(i) == 1) {
            cout << i << " is a Prime Number." << endl;
        }
        else {
            if (primecheck(i) == 2) {
                cout << i << " is not a Prime Number." << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    keep_window_open();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just step through the for loop in primecheck for x = 1. The first prime is 2. 1 is less than 2, so the first condition is met and the loop breaks. Then nothing is returned. Also, don't you think it's kind of cheating to have a list of all the primes less than 100 in your program to find the primes less than 100?

Comment: I use a vector of prime numbers because the author suggest to create it.
You are right about number 1, but what 2, 3, 4 and 5 ?
Furthermore I see 49, 77, 91 that are listed as primes (while not)! :@

Comment: None of the answer below works for me! :@

I have pasted codes but nothing...

Comment: @Leo This might be a useful link http://stackoverflow.com/q/13207417/4927751

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very wrong and you should rewrite it. 
Not all paths have return statement and you must use i instead of prime[i]

There's simple working code:

```
int primecheck(int x) {

    for (int prime : primes) {
       if (x < prime) {
          return 2;
      }else if (x == prime) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 2;
}
```

Comment: You're right, it works!

I was writing the same condition about searching in the vector and excluding what is not included in it... More simple and logic!

Just putting out last "return 2" and it works perfectly for me!

Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

`for (int i : primes)` is different than `for(int i = 0;i < terminating condition; ++i)`.

You can think of `for(int i : primes)` as "For every `int i` in the container `primes`, do something.", and `for(int i = 0; i < terminating condition; ++i)` as "for every `int i` up to terminating condition, do something"

Try this for your loop:

```
for (int i : primes) {
    if (x <= i)
        break;
    if (i == x)
        return 1;
    while (x % i != 0) {
        --i;
        if (i < 0) {
            return 1;
            break;
        }
        else {
            if (x % i == 0)
            return 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int primecheck(int x) {
   int flag=1;
   for (int i =2;i<x;i++) 
   {
     if(x%i)
       flag=2;   
   }
   return flag;
}
```

Please change your function and avoid the array